# How to track errors in the react-admin dataProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, bug-tracking, rollbar

I've installed Rollbar, a bug tracker, into my react-admin app and it works great for uncaught errors, but errors thrown by the dataProvider are not being sent to Rollbar.

I think errors thrown by the dataProvider are caught somewhere within react-admin and a notification is shown to the user so they are no longer "uncaught". Is there a simple way to get these errors sent to Rollbar?

For example, my dataProvider looks like this

```
const dataProvider = (type, resource, params) => {
    throw new Error('foo')
}
```

Rollbar is installed with a single script tag at the top of the page. See https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/browser-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-admin is catching the provider error because it's trying to display an appropriate user-facing error message for it.

I'm not familiar with Rollbar, but according to the [docs](https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/rollbarjs-configuration-reference#section-rollbar-handleuncaughtexception-), it should be possible to explicitly report errors with `handleUncaughtException()`. So maybe try something like this:

```
const dataProvider = (type, resource, params) => {
    try {
        // data provider code
    }
    catch (err) {
        rollbar.handleUncaughtException('data provider error', null, null, null, err);
        throw err; // let react-admin display its error message
    }
}
```

That's assuming a `rollbar` global is available, of course – not sure if it actually works that way.